# ReactNativeHost coming null

Tags: android, react-native

I am creating some of my android app pages in React native. So for that I am creating activity that extend ReactActivity(FaceBook React Package). But I am randomly getting NULL POINTER exception in ReactActivityDelegate.onResume,ReactActivityDelegate.onPause. Basically whereever in ReactActivityDelegate getReactNativeHost is accessed. I believe `getReactNativeHost` is returning null.

I have overridden getReactNativeHost` in MyApplication class that implements ReactApplication. And reactnativehost instance is intialised in onCreate of MyApplication class

```
mReactNativeHost = new MyReactNativeHost(MyApplicationContext);                         
mReactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager().createReactContextInBackground();
```

StackTrace is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.facebook.react.n.b()' on a null object reference
       at com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.onResume(SourceFile:124)
       at com.facebook.react.ReactActivity.onResume(SourceFile:66)
       at com.myreact.react.MyReactActivity.onResume(SourceFile:136)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1269)
       at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6770)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3477)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3546)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2795)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

Comment: If it is always in those circumstances and not in others, what do you mean by "randomly"?

Comment: Randomly means it's not always coming. But it is coming on same line